# How to capture double-click event in md-chip, using ng-dblclick?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, md-chip

I'm looking for a way to capture double-click event, using ng-dblclick in md-chip directive.

but every-time I double click over the input field it gives me the following error. I suspect that it doesn't support ng-dblclick.
[image]

**Client side code**

```
<md-chips ng-model="keyset3" 
          name="keyset3" 
          readonly="readonly"
          md-removable="removable"
          md-max-chips="5" 
          placeholder="Enter a Keyword..." 
          ng-dblclick="fieldDoubleClick('keyset3')">
    <md-chip-template>
        <strong>{{$chip}}</strong>
    </md-chip-template>
</md-chips>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's more likely because `this.items` (wherever that code is) isn't an array. Can we see the `ng-repeat` and where/how you're setting the variable used there?

Comment: @MatthewCawley thanks man, you solved my problem, actually fieldDoubleClick implementation set the value of keyset3 (which is model) straight away, without converting it into a array. Which was the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Earlier fieldDoubleClick  Implementation**

```
$scope.fieldDoubleClick = function(fieldName, type) {
    utils.setValue($scope,fieldName,utils.removeEscapeCharacters($scope.extractedData.text));                                 
}
```

**New fieldDoubleClick Imp**

```
$scope.fieldDoubleClick = function(fieldName, type) {


          if(type=="chip") {
              var arr = [];
              arr.push(utils.removeEscapeCharacters($scope.extractedData.text));
              utils.setValue($scope, fieldName, arr);
          } else {
              utils.setValue($scope, fieldName, utils.removeEscapeCharacters($scope.extractedData.text));                 
          }

      }
```

Solution - The model for the chip need to be an Array. (Provided by - Matthew Cawley)